# ClassCastException while getting int[][] from Bundle after proGuard

Tags: android, proguard, classcastexception

I've spent several days already on this issue but still can't neither understand it nor google anything somehow related to issue.

In my game I have `int[8][8]` array - gameFieldArray.
For saving game state during screen rotation or receiving call etc I used putting it to Bundle in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` :

```
outState.putSerializable(SC.SAVE_GAME_FIELD, gl.getGameField());
```

and then in `onCreate` I retrieved array:

```
gameFieldArray = (int[][])savedInstanceState.getSerializable(SC.SAVE_GAME_FIELD);
```

Everything worked fine untill I started releasing signed apk's and giving them to friends for some pre-release testing.
Signed apk's are processed by proGuard with following settings:

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontwarn android.support.**
-verbose

-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify

-keepattributes *Annotation*, SourceFile, LineNumberTable, Signature
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

 -keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
  void set*(***);
  *** get*();
 }

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

#ACRA-specific:
-keep class org.acra.ACRA {
    *;
}

-keep class org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode {
    *;
}

-keepnames class org.acra.sender.HttpSender$** {
    *;
}

-keepnames class org.acra.ReportField {
    *;
}

-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void addCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void putCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void removeCustomData(java.lang.String);
}

-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void handleSilentException(java.lang.Throwable);
}
```

Now about steps to reproduce:
only one of my friends is able to reproduce this. I assume that is because he has galaxy 9001 with 512 MB onboard.
When he plays:

```
    1) he recieves call
    2) talks, hangs up
    3) game crashes
```

This is what i have from ACRA:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.game.maxstr8/com.game.maxstr8.GameFieldForAI}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to int[][]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2185)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to int[][]
at com.game.maxstr8.f.<init>(GameLogic.java:36)
at com.game.maxstr8.GameField.onCreate(GameField.java:192)
at com.game.maxstr8.GameFieldForAI.onCreate(GameFieldForAI.java:24)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
... 11 more
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to int[][]
at com.game.maxstr8.f.<init>(GameLogic.java:36)
at com.game.maxstr8.GameField.onCreate(GameField.java:192)
at com.game.maxstr8.GameFieldForAI.onCreate(GameFieldForAI.java:24)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

No other phone (with bigger amount of RAM) or emulator reproduced this.
This is only when apk is with proguard, without it everything works fine.
This is only when taking call. When just switching orientation during game - same code gets executed but no crash occurs.

Does anybody have any leads? Any help to investigate this will be appreciated!

**Added later:**
that `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to int[][] at com.game.maxstr8.f.<init>(GameLogic.java:36)` is actually

```
gameFieldArray = (int[][])savedInstanceState.getSerializable(SC.SAVE_GAME_FIELD);
```

- retrieving int[][] array from saved Bundle.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your Proguard config. However, the ACRA error points to the `GameLogic`class at line 36. Maybe check this first. Are there any proprietary codes in GameLogic class you don't want others to see (if they decompile your app)? If not, try adding `-keep class <source_path>.GameLogic...` and see if the error goes away.

Comment: @ChuongPham I modified the end of my question - that's where exception occurs. Also: it's almost no problem to keep GameLogic, but I bet this can be resolved - I'm sure proguard can't do any bad since it is widely used.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your update above. You might try to keep the class and see if the error goes away. If not, visit Proguard website and drop a line to Eric LaFortune and ask if he can help you.

Comment: I don't see how the code could go wrong, even with ProGuard. If the code works fine on other devices, this may be a bug on this phone. It may be very hard to figure out what triggers it exactly. You could try reproducing it in a small sample app.